# Booting ubuntu USB on Windows

Tags: boot, usb

I have installed ubuntu on a USB stick and I want to be able to boot it on a Windows laptop which it wasn't created on, the option isn't there when I open the BIOS but if I try and boot it on the pc it was created on a black grub screen appears and boot command fails with the message load the kernel first.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not all laptops and PC's have the ability to boot from a USB device. If the option is not in the BIOS, it is not a feature that is supported. You may want to look into updating your BIOS, a more recent version may support USB booting.

Answer (score 0):

If the BIOS allows you to boot from a CD, you can [boot a USB device by first booting with a plop boot disk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d7b4F6QJhVM)

You can create a bootable USB linux stick with [UNetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/). Test the Ubuntu boot-stick on a known-good PC that can boot from USB first, then try it with the plop boot disk..